# How can I prevent unauthenticated users from downloading an attachment?

Tags: community, security, attachment, authentication, authorization

I have a community and internal links to attachments. They end with ...servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={ID} 
When the user clicks the link, a window.open(fileUrl) is called. This prompts to download. However if a user copy / pastes the link in an email and sends it to someone else, authenticated or not, the recipient is allowed to also download the file. This is obviously a problem. How can we prevent unauthenticated users who have a link from access? I thought they would be redirected to community login page. How can I mitigate this? It appears the communities security isn't configured correctly.

Comment: Notes and Attachments inherit permissions of the parent object, I would start there.

Comment: ok I am pretty new to Salesforce. There is a custom object my_object__c, and this is an attachment. What permission do I set to only allow Salesforce users and Authenticated Community Users to download it? That would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: There are a lot of ways you could tackle this. What have you tried to solve this problem so far?

Comment: I tried posting on here for help. So far no luck

Comment: Give this Trailhead a shot: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/data_security/data_security_objects

Comment: Did you ever solve for this?  Does your "Public Profile" access have read access to the parent record? and, if so, did you remove it to correct the problem?  Or, if it doesn't have access to the parent record, was there another solution found to this?